# Show that two definitions of matrix norm are in fact equivalent $\max\limits_{ x \neq 0} \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \max\limits_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, normed-spaces

I found a proof in an online course note which purports to show that two definitions of matrix norms are equivalent, however, I have some doubts regarding the proof, I would like a second pair of eyes

> Claim: $\|A\| = \max\limits_{ x \neq 0} \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} =
>  \max\limits_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$

---

Proof:

> $(\text{first show} \max\limits_{ x \neq 0} \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \leq \max\limits_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|)$
>
> Suppose $x \neq 0$, then $\max\limits_{ x \neq 0} 
>  \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \max\limits_{ x \neq 0}
>  \|A\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\|$. Let $z = \dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$, 
>   $\|z\| = 1$. Therefore, $\max\limits_{ x \neq 0} 
>  \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \leq  \max\limits_{ \|z\| =1} \|Az\| =
>  \max\limits_{ \|x\| =1} \|Ax\|$

-

> $(\text{next show:}\max\limits_{ x \neq 0} \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \geq \max\limits_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|)$
>
> Suppose that $\|x\| = 1$, therefore $\max\limits_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\| =  \max\limits_{\|x\| = 1}
>  \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \leq \max\limits_{x \neq 0}
>  \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$, where the inequality follows from maximization
>   over a superset of $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|=1\}$.

-

> Thus, $\max\limits_{ x \neq 0} \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = 
>  \max\limits_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$.

It seems that there is no justification for $\max\limits_{ x \neq 0} 
 \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \leq  \max\limits_{ \|z\| =1} \|Az\|$. It doesn't make sense, because we are maximizing over a much larger set than the unit circle. Can someone see if there is indeed a problem with the proof and if there is some opportunity to fix it?

Comment: I think you may have a misunderstanding. Usually, "equivalent" for norms $N$ and $M$ means that there are constants $C_1,C_2$ such that $C_1M(A) \leq N(A) \leq C_2M(A)$ for all $A$.

Comment: you dont need the inequalities, actually $\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\|A(x/\|x\|)\|$ from the definition of norm.

Comment: Why don't use the *bijection* between unit vectors and nonzero vectors?
$$x \leftrightarrow x / ||x||$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter That's not a bijection.

Comment: @user296602 Thx for pointing this out.  You're right.  It's better to read Masacroso's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, if $x\neq0$, then$$\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\left\|A\left(\frac x{\|x\|}\right)\right\|$$and that $\left\|\frac x{\|x\|}\right\|=1$.

Answer (score 4):

For $x\ne 0$, then $\dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\|x\|^{-1}\|Ax\|=\|\|x\|^{-1}Ax\|=\left\|A\left(\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\|\leq\max_{\|z\|=1}\|Az\|$.

Comment: How do you justify the last inequality?

Comment: So $\left\|\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right\|=1$ then put $z=\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$, so the left side is just $\|Az\|$ and hence it must be $\|Az\|\leq\max_{\|z\|=1}\|Az\|$.